# Is there a difference between programmatically adding objects to a UIViewController and a UITableViewController's prototype cell?

Tags: swift, uitableview, programmatically-created

I see videos where they add labels, etc. into the prototype section of a `UITableViewController` through the storyboard. Is this the same as if I was just adding those objects to a regular `UIViewController`?

I did try, but I was running into problems with constraints. If I copy and pasted an `NSLayoutConstraint` from a `UIViewController`, I would start receiving errors. So I assume constraints are handled differently also. For example, instead of using `view.CenterX`, it would be `contentView.CenterX` right?

Edit: I forgot to mention that I'm not exactly sure where the code should go. It seems like it should go into the `UITableViewController`, because that's where the prototype cell is, but in sample code, I see it added to the `UITableViewCell`.

Comment: The view type of both `UIViewController` and `UITableViewController` is different, the later one has `UITableView `as its `view` property. So if your view is list-like rows, and you think everything will repeat in rows, use a `UITableViewController` and add objects to your cells. Otherwise use a `UIViewController` and build up your view.

Comment: Also, when you copy an object from a `view` having constraints relative to this `view` and then paste it to another `view`, you'll have to add constraints again (not width height constraints, but top, bottom, left, right etc) since the parent view is changed.

Answer (score 0):

Usually what you do is this:

- place views and other UI components into UIViewController's root view (which is a UIView)

  or
- place prototype static cells  intoUITableViewController's root view (which is a table view)

The first case is completely flexible in terms of **layout**. It **is your responsibility** to position and size views to create a meaningful layout.

The second case is more constrained as the TableViewsimple orders all prototype cells (which themselves contain other subviews) **into vertical stack.**

Only you can tell what suits your needs better in context of particular project/app.

Comment: And those static cells are kind of like UIViewControllers? As in you add objects to its subviews?